# Morning Glory Wilting often and no Blooms

Tags: plant-health

Grew one plant from seed.  Was doing well in full sun on a trellis.  When intense heat arrived, it began wilting each day.  I added more water and it perked up each time.  Now the leaves are yellowing.  Still haven’t had a single bloom. Any suggestions?